# Magento 2.1: Custom Payment Gateway Method-Renderer JS File Is Ignored

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment, magento-2.1, payment-gateway

I'm working on implementing a payment gateway using the sample code from [Magento github](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway) on my Magento 2.1 site.

For some reason, Magento does not seems to use the new functions I added to ..[payment/method-renderer/sample_method.js](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/blob/master/sample-module-payment-gateway/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/sample_gateway.js). Let's say I have a function called getAwesomeInfo() that will return "hello world" string, I got the error function is not defined when I tried to add it to [../template/payment/form.html](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/blob/master/sample-module-payment-gateway/view/frontend/web/template/payment/form.html)

So far I have checked the following:

1. ...[/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.html](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/blob/master/sample-module-payment-gateway/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml), and confirm that include the payment component file. If I try to change the path, the site will throw error 500.
2. However, when I tried to edit the component file .../payment/sample_gateway.js and .../payment/method-renderer/sample_gateway.js, it doesn't seem to do anything. It's as if Magento either ignore the file or look up the javascript code from any else.
3. The site is currently on development mode. I have tried to disable cache and rebuild the static content, but that didn't seem to have any effect.

I may have missed something here. Any advise would be appreciate.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Well i am assuming that you are editing the the method renderer js file in the module folder. If you are doing this then you have to run the `setup:static-content:deploy` command to reflect your changes.

Magento takes js, css and other assets from pub folder. You can find the same file on this path `\pub\static\frontend\your_theme\default\en_US\Magento_SamplePaymentGateway\js\view\payment\method-renderer\sample_method.js`

You can edit the same file to reflect the changes instantly and finally put the same file inside the module directory for future deployment. Hope this will help.